# Lebesgue measure and a finite cover of the rationals in [0,1]

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have this problem with two parts with one part easy and obvious, the other part so hard. The problem goes as follows.

Consider the set $A=[0,1]\cap \mathbb{Q}$ and Lebesgue measure $\mu$.

a) Prove that for all $\epsilon>0$ there exists a covering  $(A_k)_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ of open intervals for A, such that $\sum_k \mu(A_k)<\epsilon$.

b) If $(A_k)_{k\in\{1,2,...,N\}}$ is a finite open covering for A, then $\sum_k \mu(A_k)>1$.

My thoughts for a) are as follows: Let $(r_n)\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ be chosen later. Arrange the set $A=\{a_1,a_2,\ldots\}$

For $\epsilon>0$ we let $A_k=(a_k-r_k\epsilon,a_k+r_k\epsilon)$ and then choose $(r_n)$ such that $\sum_k 2r_k<\epsilon$. This I can do :)

For b) though... I am at a loss. 
Any suggestions?

Comment: For b, the idea in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2722172/0-1-is-not-of-measure-zero/2722176#2722176 will work

Comment: Start with the case $N=2$ in b) and argue that the two intervals either touch each other or have a nontrivial intersection. Thus the two intervals cover all of $[0,1]$ except possible one (irrational ) number. Can you now extend the argument to a general $N$?

Comment: I think I can. Thanks!